# Load resource/file from test/resources using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-test

Is it possible to load a File/Resource from Maven's test/resources directory using `@Value`?

e.g. something like this:

```
@Value("${test/resources/path/to/file}") File file
```

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

```
@Value("${someFile}") FileSystemResource file;
```

but at runtime I see that it represents the working directory and not the file that in test/resources

Comment: There is no `test/resources` as that is part of the classpath so remove the `test/resources` part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything from test/resources is copied to target/test-classes just before the test phase. Those copied resources will be available on the classpath.

If you start a Spring Configuration in your test classes, there is a binding for classpath resources that allows you to inject them like this:

```
   @Value("classpath:path/to/file")
   Resource resourceFile;
```

It isn't necessary a File, since it could also come from a jar file on the classpath, but you can read it via the InputStream etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is direct way to do this.

This is alternate approach we used to initialize it through constructor:

```java
@RestController
public class FileController {

    private File file;

    public FileController(@Value("${file-name}") String filename) {
        file = new File(filename);
    }

}
```

Comment: Here, the problem remains the same: it's either relative to the current working directory or it must be an absolute file path.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ResourceUtils` to load files.

Example: `File certFile = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:certs/cert.txt");`

Then you can process it using `InputStream` like below:
`InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(certFile);`

Comment: No you cannot. As something on the classpath is generally inside a jar file and things inside a jar file aren't a `java.io.File` and hence will fail.